# Значение аргумента превышает допустимое значение для Int в graphql

Tags: golang, graphql

Использую библиотеку на golang  https://github.com/graphql-go/graphql

В запросе использую переменные graphql :

```
{
    "query": "query($barcode:Int){product(barcode:$barcode) {product_id,vendor_code,title,description} }",
    "variables": {
        "barcode": 70065925393
    }
}
```

Возникает ошибка :

```
    Variable \"$barcode\" got invalid value 70065925393.
Expected type \"Int\", found \"7.0065925393e+10\"
```

Если передавать число в 1000 раз меньше (например 10 млн), то ошибки не будет.

Если не использовать переменные graphql , то ошибок не будет. Но мне нужно использовать именно такой формат с переменными.

в коде аргумент barcode указан , как graphql.Int

```
var getProductArgs = graphql.FieldConfigArgument{
    "barcode": &graphql.ArgumentConfig{
        Type: graphql.Int,
    },
}
```

Как устранить эту проблему без переделывания в string?

Comment: Используйте [graphql.bigint](https://github.com/jalavosus/graphql-go-bigint)?

Comment: к сожалению это не сработало у меня на golang . Выдает ошибку , что   graphql.bigint неэкспортируемое свойство.  Разные написания graphql.Bigint и graphql.BigInt отдают ошибку undefined

Comment: Нашел решение , подключил пакет https://github.com/jalavosus/graphql-go-bigint/ Тип данных указывается так bigint.BigInt